# How to set the text to be aligned to center at the end of animation?

Tags: html, css, animation

This code plays animation for text "Hello World!", at the beggining of animation, text color is red. Then at the 25%, it becomes blue and **at the 50%, it becomes aligned to center**.

But when animation finish, text is moved back to the starting position and it isn't aligned to center.

So, here is my code:

```
p {
animation-name:sample;
animation-duration:3s;
}

@keyframes sample {
0% {color:red;}
50% {color:blue;}
75% {text-align:center;}
}
```

**And where is problem in my code?**

Comment: text wil not slide from left to center. to keep it there once animation is ended, use forwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `animation-fill-mode` to `forwards` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode

> **`forwards`**
>       The target will retain the computed values set by the last keyframe encountered during execution. The last keyframe depends on the value of animation-direction and animation-iteration-count:

```css
p {
animation-name:sample;
animation-duration:3s;
animation-fill-mode:   forwards ;
}

@keyframes sample {
0% {color:red;}
50% {color:blue;}
75%, 100% {text-align:center;}
}
```

```html
<p>text to colorize then center</p>
```

`text-align` **cannot** be animated, it will switch from a value to another. Only values that can be divided can be animated bits by bits.

Answer (score 0):

The end of an animation is at 100%:

```
100% {

    text-align: center;

}
```

and you need to say `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` in order to avoid it starting again

Answer (score 0):

You can add 100% as well and mention animation direction to forwards as mentioned below.

```
p {
    animation: sample 3s forwards;
    }

    @keyframes sample {
    0% {color:red;}
    50% {color:blue;}
    75% {text-align:center;}
    100% {text-align:center;}
    }
```